# Create Python Script RPM for CentOS

Tags: python, centos

I installed a minimal version of CentOS 6.3 on a virtual machine. I then used
*yum install python* to install python-2.6.6-29.e16_3.3.x86_64 to /usr/bin/.  I have a custom python script that I wrote and I want to create an RPM of it including all python dependencies so that a centOS user can use rpm command to install my python script and all needed python libraries.  Is this a common practice?  It seems like the below command is the recommend approach, but I don't have a setup.py file.  Any ideas?

```
python setup.py bdist_rpm
```

Comment: Write a `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need RMP file to be used for installation? After querying for RMP in Google Search, it gave me RMP is a "RealPlayer Metadata Package File". Which I am sure you are not looking for. However based on your other statements I can make out you are trying to create a rpm file which you want to distribute with all the dependencies, And for that you are using the command python setup.py bdist_rpm, This is usually the correct approach but the per-requisite is you need to create the setup.py. Refer to this link `http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/dist/setup-script.html`

Which talks about how to create your own setup.py file.

Comment: is it a common practice to include the python runtime with a custom python script in a RPM file?